# How to parse this json data in php?

Tags: php, json

```
{"data":[{"name":"John","sex":"M","address":{"unit":"7"}}]}
```

Comment: have you heard about json_decode?

Comment: please remove the xml and javasrcipt tags : your question is about json and php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode()` method of `PHP`.

```
<?php

// Store JSON data in a PHP variable
$json = '{"data":[{"name":"John","sex":"M","address":{"unit":"7"}}]}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
?>
```

Live example is [here](https://3v4l.org/dOjAE)

> By default the json_decode() function returns an object

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$jsonData ='{"data":[{"name":"John","sex":"M","address":{"unit":"7"}}]}';
$json_decode = json_decode($jsonData, true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_decode); 
echo '</pre>';

echo $json_decode['data']['0']['name'];
?>
```